# str_replace with the_content is not working

Tags: php, customization

I am trying to replace the a URL of the content with php. i tried the code mentioned below but it didn't work. is there any way to achieve this with php only?

```
function replace_text_wps($text){
    $replace = array(
        'https://www.facebook.com/something">' => 'https://www.instagram.com/something">',
  
    );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}
 
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps',99);
```

Comment: Does `$text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $text);` work?

Comment: I don't believe this is a WP problem/question, this looks like a generic PHP question about how to use `str_replace` with arrays, you should ask this on stackoverflow instead, and it can be simplified to just the inside of the function

Comment: @TomJNowell sad to see you marked this question as off-topic. the PHP codes are correct. the question is all about WordPress Hook

Comment: Have you confirmed this code works outside of a hook with predefined strings that you can test?

Comment: Is the text you want to replace even inside content? If you error_log or var_dump the `$text`, does the string you search for appear in there?

Comment: @TomJNowell yes, it works outside of a hook.

Comment: And you've tried not including the `99` priority? Keep in mind that the default is `10` so `99` runs quite late. You want small numbers for high priority code, not large numbers

Answer (score 1):

If you give a look at the documentation, of `str_replace` you will find your needs. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

There is 3 choices for you there :

```
function replace_text_wps($text){
    $replace = array(
        'https://www.facebook.com/something">' => 'https://www.instagram.com/something">',
    );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $text);

    // OR
    $text = str_replace(array(
        'https://www.facebook.com/something">'
    ), array(
        'https://www.instagram.com/something">'
    ), $text);
    
    // OR 
    $text = str_replace('https://www.facebook.com/something">', 'https://www.instagram.com/something">', $text);
        
    return $text;
}
 
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps',99, 1);
```

Comment: i tried all three. none of them are working

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer, forgot to add the number of parameters in the add_filter ;)

Comment: still not working, i think the problem is with hook (the_content)

Comment: Hum, probably yes, I've just tested it on a fresh install and it works. Does the file containing this is called in the functions.php in your theme ?

Comment: No, it is not..